# shell - compare files and update matching string awk/sed/diff/grep/csv

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed, diff

I need to compare 2 csv files and make modifications to the second column. I wrote out the logic out of how I would want to achieve this however, it seems to confuse the thread a lot more than I wanted too so I'll just write out the example.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

file1

```
user1,distinguishedName1
user2,distinguishedName2
user3,distinguishedName3
user4,distinguishedName4
user5,distinguishedName5
```

file2

```
user1,distinguishedName1
user3,distinguishedName13
user5,distinguishedName12
user6,distinguishedName4
```

desired outcome:

```
user1,distinguishedName1
user2,distinguishedName2
user3,distinguishedName13
user4,distinguishedName4
user5,distinguishedName12
user6,distinguishedName4
```

Comment: What have you implemented so far?

Comment: So what I ended up doing:cat file1 | sed 's/,.*$//' > file1a
cat file2 | sed 's/,.*$//' > file2a
grep -Fxf file1a file2a > file.match
var1=$(cat file1)
while read p; do
echo $p
var1=$(echo "$var1" | sed "s/$p,.*$//")
done <file.match
echo "$var1" > file1modified

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `join` command combined with `awk` command:

```
join -t',' -j1 -a1 -a2  file1 file2 | awk -F',' '{if(NF==3) $0=$1FS$3}1'
```

The output:

```
user1,distinguishedName1
user2,distinguishedName2
user3,distinguishedName13
user4,distinguishedName4
user5,distinguishedName12
user6,distinguishedName4
```

---

*Explanation*:

-- for ***join*** command:

`-t','` - defines field separator

`-j1` - tells to join on first field `1`

`-a FILENUM` - print unpairable lines coming from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2

---

-- for ***awk*** command:

`NF` - contains a total number of fields

`FS` - field separator(i.e. `,`)

`if(NF==3) $0=$1FS$3` - the condition, checks if there's a complement third field(as result of joining the files on lines with common first field) to perform the replacement

https://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F, '!a[$1]++' file2 file1

user1,distinguishedName1
user3,distinguishedName13
user5,distinguishedName12
user6,distinguishedName4
user2,distinguishedName2
user4,distinguishedName4
```

this order is based on file2 and file1 record order, if you want sorted order just pipe to sort

```
awk ... | sort
```